# MongoMapper: How do you save a model instance bypassing validations but not callbacks?

Tags: validation, mongomapper

Is there a way to save a MongoMapper model instance such that validations are not performed but callbacks are called? This would be analagous to ActiveRecord's `whatever.save(false)`

I found a snippet of code online that can be used to bypasses both validations and callbacks:

```
doc = whatever.to_mongo
Whatever.collection.save(doc, :safe => true)
```

So if there is an easy way to also manually run callbacks, I could use that along with the above snippet above to do it. But that would still be an inelegant and verbose way to do something relatively simple -- I'm hoping there is a simple way build into the API to skip just validations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer:

```
whatever.save :validate => false
```